# Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I wonder why 'Y' returns 2012 while 'y' returns 2011 in `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("Y").format(new Date())); // prints 2012
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("y").format(new Date())); // prints 2011
```

Can any one explain why?

Comment: Just as a note to future readers: this behavior will only happen during the last week of the year or the first week of the year.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

[week year](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year) and year. From javadoc

> A week year is in sync with a WEEK_OF_YEAR cycle. All weeks between
>   the first and last weeks (inclusive) have the same week year value.
>   Therefore, **the first and last days of a week year may have different
>   calendar year values.**
>
> For example, January 1, 1998 is a Thursday. If getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   MONDAY and getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() is 4 (ISO 8601 standard
>   compatible setting), then week 1 of 1998 starts on December 29, 1997,
>   and ends on January 4, 1998. The week year is 1998 for the last three
>   days of calendar year 1997. If, however, getFirstDayOfWeek() is
>   SUNDAY, then week 1 of 1998 starts on January 4, 1998, and ends on
>   January 10, 1998; the first three days of 1998 then are part of week
>   53 of 1997 and their week year is 1997.

Comment: `$ date
Wed Dec 30 00:42:51 UTC 2015`

`$ date +%G
2015`

`$ date +%Y
2015`

Some software is confused: `strftime` computes today (12/29/2015) as having week 53, and week-year as 2015.

Answer (score 11):

Here's a Java 8 update with some code, as GregorianCalendar will probably be deprecated or removed from future JDK versions.

The new code is handled in the `WeekFields` class, and specifically for the lower case `y` / upper case `Y` with the [`weekBasedYear()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/WeekFields.html#weekBasedYear--) field accessor.

> Returns a field to access the year of a week-based-year based on this
>   WeekFields. This represents the concept of the year where weeks start
>   on a fixed day-of-week, such as Monday and each week belongs to
>   exactly one year. This field is typically used with dayOfWeek() and
>   weekOfWeekBasedYear().
>
> Week one(1) is the week starting on the getFirstDayOfWeek() where
>   there are at least getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek() days in the year. **Thus,
>   week one may start before the start of the year. If the first week
>   starts after the start of the year then the period before is in the
>   last week of the previous year.**
>
> This field can be used with any calendar system.
>
> In the resolving phase of parsing, a date can be created from a
>   week-based-year, week-of-year and day-of-week.
>
> In strict mode, all three fields are validated against their range of
>   valid values. The week-of-year field is validated to ensure that the
>   resulting week-based-year is the week-based-year requested.
>
> In smart mode, all three fields are validated against their range of
>   valid values. The week-of-week-based-year field is validated from 1 to
>   53, meaning that the resulting date can be in the following
>   week-based-year to that specified.
>
> In lenient mode, the year and day-of-week are validated against the
>   range of valid values. The resulting date is calculated equivalent to
>   the following three stage approach. First, create a date on the first
>   day of the first week in the requested week-based-year. Then take the
>   week-of-week-based-year, subtract one, and add the amount in weeks to
>   the date. Finally, adjust to the correct day-of-week within the
>   localized week.

The setup of this `WeekFields` instance depends on the locale and may have different settings depending on it, US and European countries like France may have a different day as start of the week.

For example the `DateFormatterBuilder` of Java 8, instantiate the parser with the locale, and use this locale for the `Y` symbol :

```
public final class DateTimeFormatterBuilder {
    ...

    private void parsePattern(String pattern) {
        ...
                } else if (cur == 'Y') {
                    // Fields defined by Locale
                    appendInternal(new WeekBasedFieldPrinterParser(cur, count));
                } else {
        ...


    static final class WeekBasedFieldPrinterParser implements DateTimePrinterParser {
        ...

        /**
         * Gets the printerParser to use based on the field and the locale.
         *
         * @param locale  the locale to use, not null
         * @return the formatter, not null
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the formatter cannot be found
         */
        private DateTimePrinterParser printerParser(Locale locale) {
            WeekFields weekDef = WeekFields.of(locale);
            TemporalField field = null;
            switch (chr) {
                case 'Y':
                    field = weekDef.weekBasedYear();
                    if (count == 2) {
                        return new ReducedPrinterParser(field, 2, 2, 0, ReducedPrinterParser.BASE_DATE, 0);
                    } else {
                        return new NumberPrinterParser(field, count, 19,
                                                       (count < 4) ? SignStyle.NORMAL : SignStyle.EXCEEDS_PAD, -1);
                    }
                case 'e':
                case 'c':
                    field = weekDef.dayOfWeek();
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    field = weekDef.weekOfWeekBasedYear();
                    break;
                case 'W':
                    field = weekDef.weekOfMonth();
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("unreachable");
            }
            return new NumberPrinterParser(field, (count == 2 ? 2 : 1), 2, SignStyle.NOT_NEGATIVE);
        }

        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

---

Here's some example

```
System.out.format("Conundrum                         : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd'T'HHmms'S'")));
System.out.format("Solution                          : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd'T'HHmms'S'")));


System.out.format("JVM Locale first day of week      : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.format("US first day of week              : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.format("France first day of week          : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).getFirstDayOfWeek());
System.out.format("JVM Locale min days in 1st week   : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.getDefault()).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
System.out.format("US min days in 1st week           : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.US).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());
System.out.format("JVM Locale min days in 1st week   : %s%n",
                  WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).getMinimalDaysInFirstWeek());

System.out.format("JVM Locale week based year (big Y): %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")).get(WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).weekBasedYear()));
System.out.format("France week based year (big Y)    : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")).get(WeekFields.of(Locale.FRANCE).weekBasedYear()));
System.out.format("US week based year (big Y)        : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC")).get(WeekFields.of(Locale.US).weekBasedYear()));
```

And in regard of the locale and the upper case `Y`, you can either play with the command line option `-Duser.language=` (`fr`, `en`, `es`, etc.), or force the locale at invocation time :

```
System.out.format("English localized                 : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd'T'HHmms'S'", Locale.ENGLISH)));
System.out.format("French localized                  : %s%n",
                  ZonedDateTime.of(2015, 12, 30, 0, 0, 0, 0, ZoneId.of("UTC"))
                               .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYYMMdd'T'HHmms'S'", Locale.FRENCH)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Format `Y` to get  week year if calendar support week year. (`getCalendar().isWeekDateSupported()`)

Answer (score 0):

I learned the hard way the JSTL tag library `format:date` with `short` as the requested format uses YYYY under the covers. Which can indeed roll the printed date ahead a year.

Answer (score 0):

I convert a date back and forth - you would expect the same year when you do this.

Notice how it advances one!

This is bad: YYYY!
[image: YYYY]

You can run it [here](https://code.sololearn.com/c0EYUAOc92uQ/#java).

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import static java.lang.System.out;
class Playground {
    public static Date convertYYYYMMDDStr(String s) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date result = null;
        try {
            result = sdf.parse(s);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static String formatDateToStrWithSDF(Date d, SimpleDateFormat s) {
        return s.format(d);
    }
    public static void main(String[ ] args) {
        // DON'T DO. Use yyyy instead of YYYY
        SimpleDateFormat sdfdmy = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-YYYY"); 
        String jan1st2020sb = "2020-01-01";
        Date jan1st2020d = convertYYYYMMDDStr(jan1st2020sb);
        String jan1st2020sa = formatDateToStrWithSDF(jan1st2020d, sdfdmy);
        out.println(jan1st2020sb);
        out.println(jan1st2020d);
        out.println(jan1st2020sa);
        String dec31st2020sb = "2020-12-31";
        Date dec31st2020d = convertYYYYMMDDStr(dec31st2020sb);
        String dec31st2020sa = formatDateToStrWithSDF(dec31st2020d, sdfdmy);
        out.println(dec31st2020sb);
        out.println(dec31st2020d);
        out.println(dec31st2020sa);
    }
}
```

This is good: yyyy

[image: yyyy]