# java.util.Date is generating a wrong date?

Tags: java, simpledateformat, java.util.date

Here's my code:

```
java.util.Date TODAY = new java.util.Date();     
SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat( "YYYY-MM-DD" );
System.out.println ( SDF.format( TODAY ) );'
```

And the result is:

> 2015-02-33

But today's date is 2015-02-02!

What may be the reason behind this wrong output?

Comment: `DD` is day in year.

Comment: Use `yyyy-MM-dd` instead, see the patterns: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html.

Comment: DD is not the date in the month and YYYY is not the year.

Comment: `YYYY` would give nasty surprises around new year time! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What may be the reason behind this Wrong Output ?

Your assumptions about the date format string are wrong, the output is *correct*.

```
y   Year
Y   Week year
D   Day in year
d   Day in month
M   Month in year
m   Minute in hour
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

`Y` Week year will usually give incorrect results around new year. `D` will give incorrect results from February. So your format appeared fine most of last month.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use the `yyyy` year and `dd` day of the month.

However, I suggest you migrate to JSR-310 which is built into Java 8 and available for earlier versions of Java.  The same code is

```
System.out.println(LocalDate.now());
```

prints

```
2105-02-02
```

Comment: I concur. I tend to prefer `LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())` to make explicit that getting today’s date is a time zone dependent operation and that you have made a choice of time zone to use.

Answer (score 1):

When format for SimpleDateFormat is specified as follows:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-DD");
```

- the YYYY - means [week year](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year),
- the MM   - means month,
- the **DD**   - means **day in year**.

Week year here is not what you wanted. [See what is week year.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#week_year)

[Your today's date is 2015-02-02, which means that it is **32 days since the beginning of the year 2015 passed** and your are on the **33 day**](http://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=01&m1=01&y1=2015&d2=02&m2=02&y2=2015). That is why you get date **"2015-02-33"**.

To mean **year** (and not week year) and **day in month** change format to SimpleDateFormat("**yyyy**-MM-**dd**");