# Different values when parsing date

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have the following DateFormat

```
private static final String DATE_TIME_PATTERN = "MM/dd/YY hh:mm";
private static final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_TIME_PATTERN);
```

And when I try to parse a date it is being changed:

```
public static void main(String [] args) throws ParseException {
    Calendar futureDate = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("TODAY                   " + dateFormat.format(futureDate.getTime()));
    futureDate.add(Calendar.WEEK_OF_MONTH, 4);
    String todayPlusFourWeeks = dateFormat.format(futureDate.getTime());

    System.out.println("TODAY + 4 weeks         " + todayPlusFourWeeks);

    Calendar futureDate2 = Calendar.getInstance();
    futureDate2.setTime(dateFormat.parse(todayPlusFourWeeks));


    System.out.println("TODAY + 4 weeks         " + dateFormat.format(futureDate2.getTime()));
}
```

I got:

```
TODAY                   07/22/15 05:46
TODAY + 4 weeks         08/19/15 05:46
TODAY + 4 weeks         12/28/15 05:46
```

In the third print I'm getting 12/28/15 05:46 ?
What I'm missing at the moment of parsing that String ?

Comment: Good. Problem solved, thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat

Comment: @Federico If, rather than posting, you had examined any of the [hundreds of similar Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+date+parsing) on StackOverflow you could have taken working example code. By comparing you would have seen the problem.