# SimpleDate format returns false date for Date which is greater than 28th December

Tags: java

I am using following code to convert date value to string.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");
    String dateInString = "27-Dec-2014";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

        String dateString = null;
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
        dateString = sdf.format(date);
        System.out.println("Date generated by getFormattedDate "+dateString);


    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

If we use any date before 28th December it works fine.
It produces following output.

```
   Sat Dec 27 00:00:00 IST 2014
27-Dec-2014
Date generated by getFormattedDate 2014-12-27 12:00:00
```

If we use date as 28th December then it generates date for next year.

```
String dateInString = "28-Dec-2014";
```

It produces following output.

```
    Sun Dec 28 00:00:00 IST 2014
28-Dec-2014
Date generated by getFormattedDate 2015-12-28 12:00:00
```

Can anyone suggest why it is returning next year date for date which is greater than 27 december?

Comment: Y and y have different meanings. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.