# NSDateFormatter outputting incorrect year

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date timestamp in milliseconds:
`145146240000`

I create an NSDate object from that timestamp:

```
NSTimeInterval seconds = [@"1451462400000" doubleValue] / 1000.0f;
NSDate *transactionDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds];
NSLog(@"%@", transactionDate);
```

I log the value of `transactionDate`: **2015-12-30 08:00:00 +0000**

I then output this date using an `NSDateFormatter`:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM YYYY"];
NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:transactionDate]);
```

This incorrectly outputs the year to be **2016!**:

`30 December 2016`

How can this be? My local timezone is GMT+2 so if anything it could be off by two hours when parsed by the formatter but not an entire year!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use yyyy for year format like

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"d MMMM yyyy"];
```

i hope  it will help you.

for more info please have a look

[Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)