# Java - Calendar.getTime does not retrieve the date set with Calendar.setTime

Tags: java, date, calendar

I have the following code in Java

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
            Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
            date.setTime(SDF.parse("2011-02-01T00:00:00"));
            System.out.println(SDF.format(date.getTime()));
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
}
```

I expect to see in the console the following string

```
2011-02-01T00:00:00
```

instead I see

```
2011-12-26T00:00:00
```

What can be wrong?

Comment: It all comes down to `"YYYY"` being used instead of `"yyyy"`.

Comment: Why would you expect to see `2011-02-28T00:00:00` instead of `2011-02-01T00:00:00` anyway?

Comment: @JonSkeet mistake. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @Tunaki shame on me! Thanks. If you answer the question I'll accept it. BTW, why the weird behavior?

Comment: @sthor69 Because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change the format: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

```
SimpleDateFormat SDF = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
Calendar date = Calendar.getInstance();
date.setTime(SDF.parse("2011-02-01T00:00:00"));
System.out.println(SDF.format(date.getTime()));
```

The output is 2011-02-01T00:00:00

**"Y"**: week year

**"y"**: year

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

From the documentation:

"If week year 'Y' is specified and the calendar doesn't support any week years, the calendar year ('y') is used instead. The support of week years can be tested with a call to getCalendar().isWeekDateSupported()."

In some calendar "Y" and "y" are the same, but is not the case of the gregorian calendar.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html#isWeekDateSupported%28%29