# Why TO_UTC_TIMESTAMP in hive returns wrong year?

Tags: datetime, hive, utc

Trying to run a simple query in hive CLI -

```
select to_utc_timestamp(unix_timestamp("04/24/2017 01:59:01","MM/dd/YYYY HH:mm:ss"),'EST');
```

result:

```
OK
1970-01-18 09:00:35.941
Time taken: 0.448 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Shouldn't the output be just date plus 4 hours?

Comment: `to_utc_timestamp` expects an actual timestamp as the input, which is not what you get from `unix_timestamp`.  `to_utc_timestamp("2017-04-24 01:59:01","EST")` works just fine.

Comment: Thats not true. It accepts UNIX time stamp i.e bigint too. It says in hive documentation `{any primitive type}* = including timestamp/date, tinyint/smallint/int/bigint, float/double, decimal. E.g. to_utc_timestamp(0.123,'PST') returns 1970-01-01 08:00:00.123`

Comment: Originally the documentation referred only to timestamp arguments. What you are quoting was my recent addition to the documentation. However, it seems things are a little bit more complected. I have just updated the documentation https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-DateFunctions

Comment: P.s.- nice catch, thank you :-)

Comment: Thank you for updating description!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `yyyy` (and not `YYYY`)
2. `unix_timestamp` returns bigint and `to_utc_timestamp` considers integer values as milliseconds

---

```
select to_utc_timestamp(1000*unix_timestamp("04/24/2017 01:59:01","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"),'EST');
```

Comment: I wonder if there's any advantage to doing it one way vs the other? Timestamps in hive, ugh...

Comment: Just to calirfy, the reason you need to use lower case `yyyy` is because java treats capital `Y` as a week year https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat

Comment: @DanielDubovski, take a look at this lousy Java documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

Here we go.  You need to wrap your `unix_timestamp` in a `from_unixtime`.

```
select to_utc_timestamp(from_unixtime(unix_timestamp('04/24/2017 01:59:01','MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss'),'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'),"EST");
```