# Not able to insert date in JDBC

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, prepared-statement

The database I am working with has the date format as

```
DD-MON-RR
```

This is the table:

```
CREATE TABLE dependent (
     Fname     varchar2(15) not null,
     bdate     date,
);
```

I am currently trying to insert into a database using JDBC with the code

```
String insert = "INSERT INTO DEPENDENT(Fname,bdate) VALUES(?,?)";
PreparedStatement p = z.conn.prepareStatement(insert);
p.setString(1, "Billy");
String formatIn = "DD-MMM-YY";
SimpleDateFormat sdfi = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
java.util.Date inDate = sdfi.parse("29-AUG-10");
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(inDate.getTime());
p.setDate(2, sqldate);
p.executeUpdate();
```

I thought this would fit the format expected, however it keeps giving me java.sql.SQLException: Io exception: Size Data Unit (SDU) mismatch

I'm unsure how to fix this

Comment: What type is the `bdate` column in your table?

Comment: bdate is type date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe it or not, it looks as though your error has to do with the pattern you are using with `SimpleDateFormat`.  Change the following:

```
String formatIn = "DD-MMM-YY";
SimpleDateFormat sdfi = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
java.util.Date inDate = sdfi.parse("29-AUG-10");
```

to this and the problem should go away:

```
String formatIn = "dd-MMM-yy";
SimpleDateFormat sdfi = new SimpleDateFormat(formatIn);
java.util.Date inDate = sdfi.parse("29-AUG-10");
```

The `D` and `Y` speciciers denote the day in year and week year, respectively, and are probably not what you intended to use (see here: [Y returns 2012 while y returns 2011 in SimpleDateFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)).

Note that the rest of your JDBC code looks OK to me.