# {__time(DD-MM-YYYY)} is used to save Jmeter results, date is returning like 32-03-2019,33-03-2019, etc

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have used `{__time(DD-MM-YYYY)}` to save Jmeter results, results are saving successfully but date is returning like 32-03-2019, 33-03-2019, etc

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) you should use [pattern for SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html):

> D - Day in year
>   d - Day in month

Note also that

> y - Year
>   Y - [Week year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat)

so you propably want to use `dd-MM-yyyy`

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're going into wrong direction. If you're using this function in the [Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#listeners) - you should reconsider your approach as Listeners don't add any value, [listeners just consume a lot of resources and being evaluated after each sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)

You should be [running your tests in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

if you need to customise the `result.jtl` file to add a timestamp to it - go for command-line interpreter of your operating system features.

For example on Windows it would be something like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l %date:~7,2%-%date:~4,2%-%date:~10,4%-result.jtl
```

on Linux/Unix/MacOS (given [Bash shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)))

```
./jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l `date +%d-%m-%Y-result.jtl
```