# Google Apps Script not incrementing date correctly after 12/25/2021

Tags: google-apps-script

This is my first post here, so forgive me if I'm doing this wrong.  I am incrementing a year's worth of dates as follows:

```
for (i = 0; i <= 360; i++){
    bDate.setDate(bDate.getDate() + 1);
    bArray.push([Utilities.formatDate(bDate, "GMT", "M/dd/YYYY")]);
  }
```

It works just fine until 12/25/2021, at which point Apps Script decides to celebrate New Year's a few days early!!!  See below:

```
[12/22/2021], [12/23/2021], [12/24/2021], [12/25/2021], [12/26/2022], [12/27/2022], [12/28/2022], [12/29/2022], [12/30/2022], [12/31/2022], [1/01/2022], [1/02/2022]
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this some sort of bug?

Comment: The issue must be related to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat

Comment: Can you show us what `bDate` looks like?

Comment: Sure.  I declare bDate and the array right before the code in my question.  ```var bArray = [];
  var bDate = new Date(lastDate); ```  lastDate is a date that is grabbed from a sheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Explanation:

This must be a bug which is related in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat).

I know this is not a solution, but a workaround to solve your problem is to manually add the problematic dates, and then let the for loop continue with the rest of the dates.

- Another important note is to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone()` because right now you have hardcoded the timezone and this can result in getting wrong days.

### Workaround:

```
function myFunction() {
  const bArray =  
      [[ '12/22/2021' ],
       [ '12/23/2021' ],
       [ '12/24/2021' ],
       [ '12/25/2021' ],
       [ '12/26/2021' ],
       [ '12/27/2021' ],
       [ '12/28/2021' ],
       [ '12/29/2021' ],
       [ '12/30/2021' ],
       [ '12/31/2021' ]];
  const bDate = new Date(2022,0,1);
  for (i = 0; i <= 360 - bArray.length ; i++){
    bArray.push([Utilities.formatDate(bDate, SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "M/dd/YYYY")]);
    bDate.setDate(bDate.getDate() + 1);
  }
  console.log(bArray);
}
```

Comment: This seems to be it.  Thanks and thanks for the timezone note.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your error comes from the misusage of the `YYYY` which should be here `yyyy`. `Y` stands for week year and `y` for year. Please read [MisusedWeekYear](https://errorprone.info/bugpattern/MisusedWeekYear#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CWeek%20year%E2%80%9D%20is%20intended%20to,year%20specifier%20%E2%80%9Cyyyy%E2%80%9D%20instead).
And read with more attention the post [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686331/y-returns-2012-while-y-returns-2011-in-simpledateformat) given by @somario where the solution is given at the end.